# How can I use Distinct operator in C# LINQ query

Tags: c#, linq

I would like to select unique EventYear using following code in c#
Its giving duplicate values.
my table `(EventMasters)` structure is `(EventYear (string), EventCode, EventDescription)`
I want to select unique or distinct `EventYear`

```
    public ActionResult EventYearsMenu()
    {
        var eventyears = storeDB.EventMasters.Distinct().ToList().OrderByDescending(c => c.EventYear== c.EventYear.Distinct());
        return PartialView(eventyears);
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

> I want to select unique or distinct `EventYear`

Isn't it just:

```
var eventyears = storeDB.EventMasters
                        .Select(c => c.EventYear)
                        .Distinct()
                        .ToList();
```

Comment: getting following error with above code from my Index view which is calling a partial view :Error executing child request for handler 'System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil+ServerExecuteHttpHandlerAsyncWrapper'.My Index view code is :@model IEnumerable<JISH.Models.EventMaster>
@{
ViewBag.Title = " JISH News & Events"; }
<h3>JISH News & Event Page</h3>
@*<p> Select Event year from @Model.Count() years:</p>*@
<p> Click on year to see events by year:</p>

@{Html.RenderAction("EventYearsMenu", "Events");}

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
var eventyears = from Data in storeDB.EventMasters
                         where (this == that) // Write your Logic
                         select Data;

        if (eventyears != null)
        {
            /// do your code,,.,,,
        }
```

Comment: `eventyears` will never be null

Comment: After that you have to check First()

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: eventyears.first()  ... didnt you know this.. ??

Comment: I think you've mistaken, My point is `if (eventyears != null)` not required. `eventyears` cannot be null. Got it? If you have doubt try it.

Comment: ya it wont be null...i forget to make the check ...for evenyears.first()

Answer (score 0):

Try following

```
var eventyears = storeDB.EventMasters
                     .GroupBy(c=>c.EventYear)
                     .Select(items=>items.First())
                     .SelectMany(item->item)
                       .ToList()
                       .OrderByDescending(c => c.EventYear == c.EventYear.Distinct());
```

it will take distinct items (based on EventYear). (it is possible to have items with same EventYear classified as same, even though they have different values for some other properties)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var eventyears = storeDB.EventMasters.ToList()
                       .OrderByDescending(c => c.EventYear == c.EventYear).Distinct();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code.

```
var eventyears = storeDB.EventMasters.Distinct(q => q.EventYear.).ToList().OrderByDescending(c => c.EventYear);

return PartialView(eventyears);
```